# Integrating google map in iphone app 

Tags: iphone, google-maps-api-3

I am going to develop an app based on google map. In that locations will be displayed with markers or points near current location (point of interest). I have lattitude, longitude of different places and I am also able to find the distance from current location. I just want some help working on google map. Displaying places by latitude, longitude using markers.

I have the MAP View app of google map api. Please suggest me some tutorials or URL/source code which uses marked places and all that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should check these tutorials [1](http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2009/04/02/iphone-sdk-30-playing-with-map-kit/), [2](http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2009/04/03/iphone-sdk-30-playing-with-map-kit-part-2/), [3](http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2009/04/08/iphone-sdk-30-playing-with-map-kit-part-3/)

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about the Google Maps Ajax APIs (for display in a web app), then the Google documentation has [copious code examples](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/examples/index.html) and [explanatory documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/examples/index.html).

If you mean the Google-based maps that are available to native iPhone applications, then please refer to the [documentation for MapKit](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

This may be helpful [iphone-google-maps-component](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-google-maps-component/)