# How to integrate a map in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, google-maps

I followed the [**this**](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/tutorial-iphone.html) tutorial to integrate map in my iPhone app.

Here is my projectnamecontroller.m file

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
     NSString *url = @"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=London";
     NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    [webView loadRequest:request];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

At the end the map did not show up the iPhone simulator screen. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you want google map integration pls refer this previous SO question

[Integrating google map in iphone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667655/help-on-integrating-google-map-in-iphone-app)

Or you can go through `MKMapView` by following this [tutorial](http://mithin.in/2009/06/22/using-iphone-sdk-mapkit-framework-a-tutorial/)